# uncheck to do item javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to uncheck the task after you checked it? if i check the task it turns red en line-through but i want to click it again and than it turns back to normal.

Is there a simple way to complete this?

js

```
var takenLijst = document.getElementById('takenLijst');

var invulVeld = document.getElementById('invulVeld');

var voegToe = document.getElementById('voegToe');

var verwijderLijst = document.getElementById('verwijder');

var list = [];                                                          

voegToe.addEventListener('click', function() {                          
    event.preventDefault();                                             

    takenLijst.innerHTML = '';

    if (invulVeld.value !== '') {                                       
    list.push(invulVeld.value);                                         
    invulVeld.value = '';
    }

    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
    takenLijst.innerHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>';
    }

    invulVeld.focus();                                                  
});


takenLijst.addEventListener('click', function() {                      
    var taak = event.target;
    if (taak.tagName === 'LI') {                                        
        taak.className = "checked";                                    
    }
});

verwijderLijst.addEventListener('click', function() {                   
    list.length = 0;                                                    
    takenLijst.innerHTML = '';
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To do list</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ToDo.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="invulVeld"/><button id="voegToe">Taak</button><button id="verwijderLijst">Verwijder lijst</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="takenLijst">

    </ul>

    <script src="js/ToDo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint. Simple way is to make use of .toggleClass() in jquery. Declare the appropriate css class for turning it red and striked-out... then in your jquery code, attach an event handler in your checkbox, verify if it is checked or not, then toggle the class if the box is either checked or not. Or if you want a vanilla JS way, use .classList.remove() or .classList.add() to manipulate the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if *checked* class is already set and remove it.

```
takenLijst.addEventListener('click', function() {                      
    var taak = event.target;
    if (taak.tagName !== 'LI') 
        return;

    if(taak.className == "checked") {
        taak.className = "";
    } else {
        taak.className = "checked";
    }
});
```